# Vercel cant response url with port on Next JS API

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I have the following problem in my code (this is a route.js file in the api folder):

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function POST(request) {
  const { email, password } = await request.json()


  try {
    const { data } = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://app.meusite.com:9081',
      data: {email, password}    })
 

    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: 'success', user: data },
      {
        status: 200
      }
    )
  } catch (err) {
    const { response } = err
    console.log(err)
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: err },
      {
        status: response.data.status
      }
    )
  }
}
```

My problem is that when I run it locally it works fine but when in Vercel it gets timeout.

I tested other url like https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto and it worked well locally and in Vercel.

Do I have to set anything when use url:port or change sometinhg in vercel?

Thanks!

Tried differents url calls and worked. Looks the problem is with something in the vercel/next settings to use url:port